# First-person narrative of a story occurring at the moment

Tags: tenses, narration

When narrating a story from the first-person perspective in the present tense, would the following be correct?

> I wake up at 7 am and see no sunlight entering my room. Thinking I'm up too early, I decide to rest for a few more minutes.

I'm specifically asking whether the *I wake up* part is correct, or whether it should be *I woke up* instead.

Comment: Tip: the grammar part of your question is on-topic here, but if you have questions about using 1st-person narration or present tense, you might try http://writers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.

*Wake* is the correct first person singular present active form of the verb.

This is the alternative (switching tenses in the middle of the sentence):

> I woke up at 7 am and see no sunlight entering my room.

You might be better off just changing the tense of all the verbs to past, because present tense writing is seldom necessary and often slightly ambiguous; it sounds a little like you're saying, "*Every day* I wake up at 7 am..."

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, yes, you have the proper tense and usage.

However, narratives are seldom told in first-person present; even if the intent of the author is to have the story feel as if it's happening right now, the author usually chooses past tense, because we as readers are most used to that tense when being told of of events that have occurred, even if they have just occurred (as in a newspaper or breaking news).

There are notable counterexamples; Suzanne Collins wrote the bestselling *Hunger Games* trilogy in first-person present tense, I think to evoke a "therapeutic" writing style of the protagonist Katniss telling her story as if recalling a recurring nightmare.